# Express $f(x)=\sin{x}$ as an even function

Tags: fourier-series, integral-transforms

> Express $f(x)=\sin{(x)}$, with $(0 < x< \pi )$ as an even function, $f(x+ 2\pi)=f(x)$

The topic is on Fourier Series.

I have the following so far:

Since $f(x)$ must be an even function, we must only calculate the $a_n$ values, $n=1,2,...$.

- $\displaystyle a_0= \frac{2}{\pi}\int \limits_{0}^{\pi}\sin{(x)}dx = \frac{4}{\pi}$
- $\displaystyle a_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int \limits_{0}^\pi \sin{(x)}\cos{(\frac{n \pi x}{\pi})} = \frac{2}{\pi} \int \limits_{0}^\pi \sin{(x)}\cos{(nx)}dx$

I am, however, having difficulty integrating the above integral for $a_n$ using the method he wants us to use (**The table method**).
Can someone please show me how to do this integral using the tables?

Once $a_n$ is calculated, I know that I will then have my final answer in the form

$$f(x)=\sin{(x)} \sim \frac{2}{\pi} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos{(nx)}$$

Comment: @Dillon So, we're essentially looking for the Fourier series of $\lvert\sin x\rvert$? (Look at a graph to see what I mean.)

Comment: Yes, if you plot the periodic function, this looks precisely like $|\sin{(x)}|$. :)

Comment: Aren't there formulae that simplify $\sin A\cos B$? Product-to-sum formulae, or something.

Comment: Thank you - that helped me split it into two terms that I could integrate seperately, but he specifically asks us in the question to make use of the table method for integration by parts. That's what I'm having trouble with :(

Comment: Use $2\sin x\cos(nx)=\sin\bigl((n+1)x\bigr)-\sin\bigl((n-1)x\bigr)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the table method is the method, when you do integration by parts several times. So here you can just do this and get the result.
Lets denote $I = \int \limits _0 ^ \pi \sin x  \cos nx \, dx$.
Here is described the process of integration by parts (two times):

$I = \left. -\cos x \, \cos nx \, \right| _0 ^ \pi -\left. n \, \sin x \, \sin nx \, \right| _0 ^ \pi+ n^2 \int \limits _0 ^ \pi \sin x \, \cos nx \, dx = (-1)^n + 1 + n^2 \, I$.

So, $I = \frac{(-1)^n + 1}{1 - n^2}$.